# Using request and cheerio with angular full stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, request, angular-fullstack

I am a relatively new programmer, and almost completely new to node.

I have created a new project using the yo and the angular fullstack: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

and I am looking to create a scraper by using the Request module: https://github.com/request/request

I am looking to do this all within a new page I created, called testPage. I want to use Request within testPage.controller.js.

It is currently this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('siteTestApp')
  .controller('testPageCtrl', function () {
  });
```

I have added request to my package.json:

```
"request": "*",
```

so I know that it has installed through npm install.

However, I don't know how to register the module and make it so that I can use request on my testPage.

I have tried adding this within my testPage.controller, client app.js and server app.js

```
var request = require('request');
```

Once adding I've then tried this:

```
    angular.module('siteTestApp')
  .controller('testPageCtrl', function (request) {
  });
```

I've not been able to get it to work. Depending on my approach, I've been getting a number of different errors. 
- require is not found
- request is not found
- requestProvider <- request

Any help as to how I can register the request module (and probably the cheerio module) and getting it working within my testPage would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all.